# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext in oauth2

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a project which uses spring security oauth2 for secured connections.Below is my spring configuration file.

spring-security.xml :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd ">

    <!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->
        <!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
        <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
            authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
            <anonymous enabled="false" />
            <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
            <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
                parameters -->
            <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
            <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        </http>

        <!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
            and what roles have access to them -->
        <http pattern="/protected/**" create-session="never"
            entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <anonymous enabled="false" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
            <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
            <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        </http>


        <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="realmName" value="test" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
            <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

        <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

        <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
        </authentication-manager>


        <!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
            combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
            credentials from DB -->
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <authentication-provider>
                <user-service>
                    <user name="user1" password="user1" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
                </user-service>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
            <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
        </bean>


        <!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
            but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
        <bean id="tokenStore"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

        <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
            and other things -->
        <bean id="tokenServices"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
            <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
            <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
            <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="3600" />
            <property name="refreshTokenValiditySeconds" value="5270400"></property>
            <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
            <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
            <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory"/>
        </bean>
        <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" authorization-endpoint-url="/protected" token-endpoint-url="/oauth/token">
            <oauth:authorization-code />
            <oauth:implicit />
            <oauth:refresh-token />
            <oauth:client-credentials />
            <oauth:password />
        </oauth:authorization-server>

        <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
            resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

        <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
            <!-- client -->
                        <oauth:client client-id="client1"
                authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
                authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />        

        <oauth:client client-id="client1"
                authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                secret="client1" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

        </oauth:client-details-service>

        <sec:global-method-security
            pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
            <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
                http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
            <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
        </sec:global-method-security>

        <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
        <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
    </beans>
```

When i request for oauth access token using the below request am getting the access and refresh token as below.

Request is

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/SaveItMoneyOauth/oauth/token -H “Accept: application/json” -d "grant_type=password&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&username=user1&password=user1&scope=read,write,trust"
```

Response is :

```
{"value":"4796a04a-2266-4184-a1be-e4248cea7ba8","expiration":"Jul 11, 2016 12:15:34 PM","tokenType":"bearer","refreshToken":{"expiration":"Sep 10, 2016 11:15:34 AM","value":"87509989-0ea9-4372-87aa-22290ae0c98e"},"scope":["read,write,trust"],"additionalInformation":{}}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

Then when i i requested for the protected resources using below request i am getting "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" as error.

Request is :

```
curl -H "access_token=4796a04a-2266-4184-a1be-e4248cea7ba8"  "http://localhost:8080/SaveItMoneyOauth/protected/users/api"
```

I am using "2.0.7.RELEASE" as the oauth2 library.
How to solve this error.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CURL command is wrong, you need to provide the access token in the Authorization header. Try this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 4796a04a-2266-4184-a1be-e4248cea7ba8"  "http://localhost:8080/SaveItMoneyOauth/protected/users/api"
```